# While statement ignoring response value

Tags: c#, command-line, if-statement, while-loop, console-application

I have a command line asking the user to say (Y/N) and this value is passed to the checkResponse method.

For some reason the while loop ignores the value even though when I debug it's showing the value is "Y". It also continues to loop when the value is set to "N". If I move the if statements below the while statement, the program half way works. I can send up an initial value of "Y" and the while statement will ignore it and start running the code inside of it.

Any idea what I'm missing or over-looking?

Thanks in advance.

```
public void checkResponse(string response, string confirmValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    if (response == "Y")
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (response == "N")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((response != "Y") || (response != "N"))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + response + "\" is not a valid response.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered:" + confirmValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y/N)");
            response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did some more research and ended up going with the while (!response.equals("Y"))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change from `OR` to an `AND` logical operator:

```
(response != "Y") && (response != "N")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `((response != "Y") || (response != "N"))` is always `true`

Comment: Now that I say it out loud that makes perfect sense. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((response != "Y") || (response != "N"))
```

Will always be true, as the response cannot be Y and N at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. What if `while` loop terminates? We want it to back to check again:

```
public void checkResponse(string response, string confirmValue)
{
Check:
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    if (response == "Y")
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (response == "N")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((response != "Y") && (response != "N"))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + response + "\" is not a valid response.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered:" + confirmValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y/N)");
            response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        }
        goto Check;
    }
}
```

Or, better:

```
public void checkResponse(string response, string confirmValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    while (response != "Y" && response != "N")
    {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + response + "\" is not a valid response.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered:" + confirmValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y/N)");
            response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
    if (response == "N")
           Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the input is uppercase as well? You could use the [equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9) method and ignore the case.

```
message.Equals("Y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Edit: While this may be better for the error with the or instead of an and is your actual problem.

Comment: Yea, I was so confused by it, I made it write out the value before entering the loop.